# PHP preg_match: escaping { and }

Tags: php, string, escaping, preg-match

I am facing a little problem.
My string is `From {start} to {end}` and I want to validate it using `preg_match()` to avoid illegal chars.

`preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\{\} ]{1,}$/",$va`r)

The point is the escape for `{` and `}`.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape curly braces inside the square brackets:

```
preg_match('!^[a-zA-Z{} ]+$!', $var);
```

If you need to escape characters, just put a backslash (`\`) before them. **Note:** if you're using a double quoted string, you may need to escape the backslashes from interpretation there. For example:

- `'\t'` matches a tab character;
- `"\t"` *is* a tab character; and
- `"\\t"` is equivalent to '\t'.

Comment: mmm, ok 

i actually understand the problem is that string is passed by get.